# How to do autoscaling with Azure VMs?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, autoscaling

It's pretty easy to do autoscaling with Azure web apps, and there's something called Virtual Machine Scale Sets (but that's still in beta and not working properly yet), so I'm wondering: how can we do autoscaling using normale Azure VMs?

1) I was thinking we could create a load balancer, availability set and VMs, pre-provision them and turn some off. But aside from using the API to build a DIY scaler: how can I automatically turn on more machines if the current set exceeds a certain threshold? Does Azure offer anything for this? How do big companies that use Azure handle this?

2) How can I make sure that the machines are all consistent and have the latest version of our software installed on it? Even if the machine has been offline for months?

Answer (score 0):

Well, those are 2 separate questions. Nonetheless:

1. You can use VM Scale Sets to do that. [Here's](http://windowsitpro.com/azure/autoscale-iaas-azure-resource-manager) a nice compilation of resources
2. VM Scale sets can kinda achieve that, but not exactly. If the VM was offline nothing can configure it (at least in Azure). You can use Powershell DSC\Ansible\Chef\whatever to configure VM once it comes up. If you are using plain VM Scale Sets you would need to upgrade VM before bringing it up.

Comment: I don't want to use Scale Sets. It's a beta product, and I doubt anyone is using it in the real world yet.

Comment: well, I don't know where you got that from, but that's what Microsoft is using internally for a lot of things Azure is hosting. So I wouldn't be so sure. Also, its not beta, it was announced like 2-3 years ago? I can't even recall. And there's no other way (native), so best of luck with that

Comment: @LeonCullens - Your information is incorrect. Azure Scale Sets are in production, Generally Available. Not Beta. And no idea why you think they're not being used "in the real world" yet.

Comment: Well... I looked EVERYWHERE for examples on how to add VM Extensions to my scale set (so I can deploy code to the machines) but there is NO documentation about how to do that. I call that beta at best. It's so limited, and there is absolutely no documentation on how to deploy my code to a VMSS. There's just no way that big companies are using this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-dsc - that took me, ughm, 5 seconds to google? @LeonCullens, 15 more seconds - https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-custom-script-windows

Comment: @4c74356b41 you really think I didn't find that myself? Where do you see an explanation of how to use these custom scripts and extensions? I'm not seeing it. And please tone down the condescendingness, I'm just asking questions and trying to learn.

Comment: you are not, you are whining how vm scale sets are bad and beta and how you looked everywhere, but didn't find a simple thing. I don't even understand what you cant understand\find. those extensions are documented pretty extensively